# Creating of generic method which will process Share Point List

Tags: development

My current project has to process several `SP List's` from different `SPSites`,  so I've created several connector classes for each of them.

For each of them I need to query a list and return some values. I thought I should create a unique generic method for this purpose to save me some time and lines. Something like this :

```
private SPListItemCollection GetSPListItemCollectionFromSPList(string SiteName, string ListName, string queryString)
        {
            try
            {
                using (SPSite currentSite = new SPSite(SiteName))
                {
                    if (currentSite == null)
                    {
                        throw new ArgumentException("Invalid URL");
                    }
                    using (SPWeb currentWeb = currentSite.OpenWeb())
                    {
                        if (currentWeb.Lists[ListName] == null)
                        {
                            throw new Exception("There is no list with that name");
                        }
                        SPList myList = currentWeb.Lists[ListName];
                        SPQuery query = new SPQuery();

                        query.Query = queryString;
                        return myList.GetItems(query);
                    }
                }
        }
        catch (ArgumentException ex)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(ex.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }


    }
```

Method should take SPSite URL as parameter, then List Name, and finally query string.

My question is, is this a good practice , or should I avoid creating this method? If it is good practice, please propose me a good name for this method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not entirely good practice. Problem is that you return list items in an instance of *SPListItemCollection* that contains items from *SPWeb* and *SPSite* that have been disposed (as the *using* closes). While it may work for basic field values, I don't recommend doing it like that as you will run into issues with some fields or properties.

Perhaps you could do `myList.GetItems(query).Xml` and return the XML string and use that? Or serialize it to Xml and return that?

For function name, would simple `GetListItems` work?

Comment: Thank You on your comment Paolo , I thought there can be some issues when disposing  SPWeb and SPSite objects , that's the reason I've asked this question in the first place.

Comment: Yes, disposing itself is done correctly with the "using" clause.